# Must I pay NYC city tax?

Tags: united-states, non-resident, new-york, withholding

I do not live in New York City I live in central New York and work in central New York. My employer has taken out NYC city taxes. Is this a tax I, not being a resident of NYC or any of the 5 boroughs have to pay?

Comment: do you ever do any work in the city? Do you go there for a staff meeting or a training class? How long have they been withholding for city income tax?

Comment: I never go into the city for anything. I live 7 hrs away from NYC.

Comment: You may want to talk to a tax person.  Perhaps you can file a tax return from the city and receive a full refund.  You may also want to consult your HR department.  What exactly do you mean by "central NY"?  What county do you reside?

Comment: I reside in Yates County

Comment: It is in the Fingerlakes also known as Southern Tier

Comment: Does HR have your correct address?

Comment: Yes thy do have the correct one

Comment: Have you asked the company why they are taking out NYC taxes?

Comment: I just contacted our HR, hopefully they can correct this.

Answer (score 1):

From the comments:

> Does HR have your correct address?
>
> Yes thy do have the correct one

When wondering why a state or federal tax is being withheld by your employer, always look at the W-4. Providing HR with your mailing address doesn't mean that they will be able to properly withhold. You will need to complete Federal and state W-4 forms.

from the [Employee’s Withholding Allowance Certificate (IT-2104)](https://www.tax.ny.gov/pdf/current_forms/it/it2104_fill_in.pdf)

> Are you a resident of New York City?  ...........  Yes  No
>
> Are you a resident of Yonkers? .....................  Yes  No

How you answered those two questions may help determine if any City taxes are withheld.